# Two Html select drop down apply class for span element using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on HTML select Dropdown. I have two dropdowns one is for font size adjust and other is for text alignment.

When I select the fontsize from the dropdown it has to apply along with text-capitalize (bootstrap css) and If I select the font alignment all three should apply for the span element. For Example.

```
<div>
   <span id="Title"class="text-capitalize">check</span>
</div>
```

Right now the code was like this

```
function changeFont_size () {
var select = document.getElementById('font_size');
// Bind onchange event
  select.onchange = function() {
      document.querySelector("#Title").className = this.value += " text-   
      capitalize";   
     };
}
function changeAlignment () {
   var select = document.getElementById('text_align');

  // Bind onchange event
  select.onchange = function() {
    document.querySelector("#Title").className = this.value;     
 };
}
```

Actually I am newbe on Javascript. Some how I am not getting.

The output result would be the combination of :

```
<span class="h1 left text-capitalize">Text</span>
```

Everything should be in pure javascript.

Thanks in advance. Kindly help me.

Here is the [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/3p56j3oy/)

Answer (score 0):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3p56j3oy/7/) makes your code work. You need to run the code when the document is loaded, so that your onchange functions are being hooked in time.

It does not work exactly like you intended though. Your alignment classes need to be on the parent element and when you select your alignment, you disregard the previously set h1 or h2 class.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var font_size = document.querySelector('#font_size');

    // Bind onchange event
    font_size.onchange = function() {
     document.querySelector("#Title").className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value += " text-capitalize";  
    };

    var text_align = document.querySelector('#text_align');

    // Bind onchange event
    text_align.onchange = function() {
     document.querySelector("#Title").className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;    
    };
};
```

Comment: Good answer but text alignment is not working. I changed it see http://plnkr.co/edit/eeRsasDwZjLmJsPVVkU7?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things up. There are two ways to bind events (well, two ways which are still common even with recent browsers).

The first one is to put a function call in the onsomething property of an element in the html code. Whatever is put there will be executed when the event happens.

```
<button onclick="alert('hi');">Click me</button>
```

You should pass the event object to an event handler instead of writing inline code.

```
<button id="helloworld" onclick="helloworld_onclick(event)">Run</button>
...
function helloworld_onclick(e) {
    alert("Hello world!");
}
```

If you want to be able to bind events dynamically, if you want to bind multiple events to an object and if you want to keep the JavaScript outside of your HTML, the modern way to to so is with `addEventListener`.

```
document.querySelector("#helloworld").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    alert("Hello world!");
});
```

The event object passed (called `e` in my functions) contains information about what triggered the event and can be used to prevent default behavior and to control event propagation. You can't use "this" in event handlers, but the element which called the handler will be stored in `e.target`.

In your code, you created functions which, when called, bind events to the elements. Then you bound those functions to the elements with the html attributes.

Finally, you seem to be stuck between querySelector and getElementById. Note that querySelector(All) returns a static node/nodelist while getElement(s)By(...) returns a live node/nodelist. A static node is a copy of all the information about the element. A live node is a reference to the real element. If you modify the element, it modifies the live node, but the static node will keep the old information. You should use getElementById over querySelector for that, and because it runs faster. For code simplicity however, you might prefer always using querySelector. Just don't mix using `querySelector("#something")` on a line and `getElementById("something")` on another one, it's the best way to get confused and end up wasting time on a bug because you wrote `querySelector("something")` or `getElementById("#something")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeFont_size (element) {

    if(element.options[element.selectedIndex].value != 'select'){

    document.getElementById('Title').className =   element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    } else{
document.getElementById('Title').className = '' }
}
function changeAlignment (element) {

      if(element.options[element.selectedIndex].value != 'select'){

    document.getElementById('container').className = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    } else{
document.getElementById('container').className = '' }
}
```

Try this, Hope it will work